# How to install expo CLI on macbook pro big sur?

Tags: ios, react-native, npm, expo

I an having issue regarding the installation of expo on the new mac.
When I run this command:

```
npm install --global expo-cli
```

I have the error:

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/theowatine/.npm/_logs/2020-11-21T09_26_14_033Z-debug.log
```

Does anyone know what could be the solution? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This is a common issue when using a globally-installed `npm`. The [`npm` docs contain a page about it](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally).

They recommend reinstalling `node`/`npm` with a version manager (like [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)). This is often a very good option if you are developing something locally. If you do that, this problem will go away. You can stop reading this answer if you want.

They also provide a way to configure `npm` to put the globally installed items in a directory of your choosing. That is a good option too, if a version manager won't work for you for whatever reason.

Another option they mention is using `npx` instead of globally installing the tool. I use this one a lot and like it quite a bit, but it does mean that you frequently have to remember to prefix commands you see with `npx`.

There are two somewhat common options that they do not list. One is to run your install with `sudo`. This means that any lifecycle scripts will get run as root on your machine. This is generally a bad idea (which is why they don't mention it in the docs), but is very common.

Another option is to `chmod` your `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` directory such that you can write to it. This is also a not-great idea in my opinion (which is probably why it too is not mentioned in the docs), but people do it.

In the case of `expo-cli` and in most developing-something-locally cases, installing with a package manager like [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) is probably the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Works fine now!

Comment: The installation via `nvm` worked for me with macOS Catalina. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I am also using macOS Big Sur on mbp and i experienced same issue. After reading Trott's answer i downloaded node from https://nodejs.org/en/download/ and installed it. Now expo and react native working fine.

Homebrew version of node is failed to install expo at all time but direct download from nodejs.org worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
sudo npm install -g expo-cli
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am using Big sur(11.4) and I have downloaded latest version of node
https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Then run the following command for install expo and its working fine.

```
npm install --global expo-cli
```